# Remove sticky header on grouped ListView

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime app and I'm using `ListView` with only the `GroupStyle` and its `HeaderTemplate` set.

Everything works fine, except I need to disable the sticky header which is always on top while scrolling through the list, but I can't find which template I need to edit to completely disable the sticky header. And one thing that really bothers me is when I navigate away from the page, the current header disappears and a blank appears on the same spot.

The code is simple:

```
<CollectionViewSource
    x:Key="cvs"
    IsSourceGrouped="True"
    ItemsPath="GroupItems"
    Source="{Binding Categories}">
</CollectionViewSource>
```

in the `Resource`,

and the `ListView`:

```
<ListView
x:Name="ListView"
IsSwipeEnabled="False"
ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource AllGamesViewTemplateSelector}"
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
SelectionMode="None"
ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True">
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AllGamesViewCategoryTemplate}"/>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

So my question is how to disable sticky headers on grouped `ListView`?

Comment: I don't think it's the GroupStyle, I think it's more likely the ItemsPanel or the ItemsPresenter. The ItemsPresenter has HeaderTransitions that may be the cause.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and finally came across this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemsstackpanel.arestickygroupheadersenabled?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Set the AreStickyGroupHeadersEnabled property in the ListView's ItemsPanelTemplate.

```
<ListView
    x:Name="ListView"
    IsSwipeEnabled="False"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource AllGamesViewTemplateSelector}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
    SelectionMode="None"
    ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True">
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AllGamesViewCategoryTemplate}"/>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>

    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel AreStickyGroupHeadersEnabled="False"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to wrap the ListView in a ScrollViewer to prevent the sticky headers.

Comment: But then virtualization does not work, which is crucial for me, because my lists have hundreds of items

Answer (score 1):

One solution that comes to mind is not using grouping in the ListView, just simulating it. Create a collection that will hold the items for the groups and placeholder items representing the headers. Then use a template selector for the ListView to render the placeholder items as headers.